# Groovy : Compare SOAP Response with XML file

Tags: xml, groovy, compare, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

I want to compare in groovy code my Soap Response with xml file ignoring order :

Here is my code :

```
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Stuff
import org.xmlunit.Stuff

//ExpectedString is my xml converted to text, same for ResponseString

Diff diff = DiffBuilder.compare(ExpectedString)
           .withTest(ResponseString)
           .ignoreComments()
           .ignoreWhitespace()
           .checkForSimilar()
           .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byName))
           .build();

assertFalse("XML similar " + diff.toString(), diff.hasDifferences())
```

So, as you can see, I used DefaultNodeMatcher, I used XMLUnit2.0 ... with no result (even not ignoring order or having exception error while comparing)

Is there a solution ? to resolve this

As I'm desperate to find a direct one, can I sort my xml and my soap response so i can have a simple diff ? is there a way to sort it line by line alphabetically ? If yes, how ?

Thank you guys !

Update :

Here is my XML structure simplified

```
<body>
<stuff>
  <miniStuff></miniStuff>
  <miniStuff></miniStuff>
</stuff>
<Services>
  <Service>
    <tag1>ValueA</tag1>
    <tag2>ValueAA</tag2>
  </Service>
  <Service>
    <tag1>ValueB</tag1>
    <tag2>ValueBB</tag2>
  </Service>
</services>
</body>
```

My problem is I can't guarantee that ValueA is the first one and not the second

Comment: Do you have sample Data that you are trying to compare?

Comment: I'll add a simple data to my post within a minutes, thank you :)

Comment: @Rao : Ready bro :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the one you might looking for:  use `ByNameAndTextRecSelector`

```
withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(new ByNameAndTextRecSelector(),ElementSelectors.byName))
```

**Unit Test:**

```
    @Test
    public void testDiffOrder() {
        final String control = """
            <r>
                <ser>
                    <t1>a</t1>
                    <t2>b</t2>
                </ser>
                <ser>
                    <t1>d</t1>
                    <t2>e</t2>
                </ser>
            </r>"""
        final String test = """
            <r>
                <ser>
                    <t1>d</t1>
                    <t2>e</t2>
                </ser>
                <ser>
                    <t1>a</t1>
                    <t2>b</t2>
                </ser>
            </r>"""
        Diff diff = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromString(control))
                .withTest(Input.fromString(test))
                .ignoreComments()
                .ignoreWhitespace()
                .checkForSimilar()
                .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(new ByNameAndTextRecSelector(),ElementSelectors.byName))
                .build()

        assertFalse("XML differ " + diff.toString(), diff.hasDifferences())
    }
```

Credits to @bodewig.
Sample from [here](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/blob/803876a1a63647008caeb9407b78ed3fe7e1f916/xmlunit-core/src/test/java/org/xmlunit/diff/ByNameAndTextRecSelectorTest.java)

**UPDATE: more groovified version**with OPs original xml snippet.

```
import org.xmlunit.builder.DiffBuilder
import org.xmlunit.builder.Input
import org.xmlunit.diff.ByNameAndTextRecSelector
import org.xmlunit.diff.DefaultNodeMatcher
import org.xmlunit.diff.ElementSelectors

def control = """<body>
   <stuff>
      <miniStuff />
      <miniStuff />
   </stuff>
   <Services>
      <Service>
         <tag1>ValueB</tag1>
         <tag2>ValueBB</tag2>
      </Service>
      <Service>
         <tag1>ValueA</tag1>
         <tag2>ValueAA</tag2>
      </Service>
   </Services>
</body>"""
def test = """<body>
   <stuff>
      <miniStuff />
      <miniStuff />
   </stuff>
   <Services>
      <Service>
         <tag1>ValueA</tag1>
         <tag2>ValueAA</tag2>
      </Service>
      <Service>
         <tag1>ValueB</tag1>
         <tag2>ValueBB</tag2>
      </Service>
   </Services>
</body>"""
def myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromString(control))
            .withTest(Input.fromString(test))
            .checkForSimilar()
            .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(new ByNameAndTextRecSelector(),ElementSelectors.byName))
            .build()
println myDiff.toString()
println myDiff.hasDifferences()
assert !myDiff.hasDifferences()
```

Comment: @HamzaAmami, glad to know that it is helpful.