# Tag number in an xml with groovy

Tags: xml, soapui

IS there a way to compare all tags in two xml ?
I'm using xmlunit2.3 to do some other stuff.

Example :
XML1 :

```
<A>
<a>
<b>
</A>
<B>
<a>
<b>
<c>
</B>
```

Size of XML1 = 9

XML2 :

```
<A>
<a>
<b>
</A>
<B>
<a>
<b>
</B>
```

Size of XML2 = 8

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well I just find all occurrence of (<) on my xml, as a first solution.

Comment: What you have tried? May be you can check this one and see if this is helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743664/groovy-compare-soap-response-with-xml-file/40745555#40745555

Comment: I searched the occurence of "<" in both xml to find the number of tags in  an xml file

Comment: That may not be good way, because in case if there is `CDATA` and it has `<` as part of data, then it may results incorrect. By the way, try the solution mentioned in the above link.

Comment: Ok, thanks bro !
But the solutions above is for recursive compare, I want to calculate a size of a Soap

Comment: What do you mean by size of soap¿

Comment: number of all tags , an xml file that contains <value></value> have a size of 2.

Comment: Have you tried the given link in the first comment? Or at least provide the xml snippet closure of your data because what you quoted is not even well formed xml.

Answer (score 0):

This check has to be done in the XMLParser you are using, either your own or a existing. The XML language does support it.