# Compare two XML files with child nodes that are not in sequence using xmlunit 2.3.0

Tags: groovy, soapui, xmlunit-2

I want to compare two XML files in SoapUI (Groovy) which are similar but the child nodes are not in sequence. I'm using XML unit v2.3.0.

```
XML1:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
</env:Header>
<soap:Body>
<Details>
<RateType RateTypeID="6">
    <RateType>AAAAA</RateType>
    <BaseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <UOM>percent</UOM>
</RateType>
<RateType RateTypeID="3">
    <RateType>BBB</RateType>
    <BaseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <UOM>percent</UOM>
</RateType>
<RateType RateTypeID="41">
    <RateType>CCC</RateType>
    <BaseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <UOM>percent</UOM>
</RateType>
<RateType RateTypeID="43">
    <RateType>DDD</RateType>
    <BaseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <UOM>percent</UOM>
</RateType>
</Details>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

XML2:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
</env:Header>
<soap:Body>
<Details>
<RateType RateTypeID="41">
    <RateType>CCC</RateType>
    <BaseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <UOM>percent</UOM>
</RateType>
<RateType RateTypeID="43">
    <RateType>DDD</RateType>
    <BaseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <UOM>percent</UOM>
</RateType>
<RateType RateTypeID="6">
    <RateType>AAAAA</RateType>
    <BaseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <UOM>percent</UOM>
</RateType>
<RateType RateTypeID="3">
    <RateType>BBB</RateType>
    <BaseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <UOM>percent</UOM>
</RateType>
</Details>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In the above example both the XML's are similar in content but only the sequence differs. I want to compare both of them to know if they are equal.

When I ran the below code:

```
Diff myDiffSimilar = DiffBuilder.compare(XML1))
            .withTest(XML2)
            .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder().whenElementIsNamed("Rate").thenUse(ElementSelectors.selectorForElementNamed("RateValue", ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes)).build()))
            .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder().whenElementIsNamed("RateType").thenUse(ElementSelectors.selectorForElementNamed("RateType", ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes)).build()))
            .checkForSimilar().build();

log.info myDiffSimilar.getDifferences().toString();
```

It gives me the following output

```
[Expected child '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope' but was 'null' - comparing <soap:Envelope...> at /Envelope[1] to <NULL> (DIFFERENT), Expected child 'null' but was '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope' - comparing <NULL> to <soap:Envelope...> at /Envelope[1] (DIFFERENT)]
```

Can someone advice me on the element selector/conditional builder that should be used in this scenario?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would certainly help for anyone who would like to reproduce your output if you could post your XML as text and not as an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743664/groovy-compare-soap-response-with-xml-file

Comment: @Rao  Not Really... Tried that already... Here is the output..                     Expected child nodelist length '17' but was '16' - comparing..........................
true
false

Comment: I could compare successfully. Would it be possible for a screen shot of full attack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :

```
Diff diff = DiffBuilder.compare(actual)
            .withTest(expected)
            .ignoreComments()
            .ignoreWhitespace()
            .checkForSimilar()
            .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(new ByNameAndTextRecSelector(), ElementSelectors.byName))
            .build();

assert diff.hasDifferences()==false
```